# extjs combo box auto click drop down arrow

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am now using extjs 2.3. I have a editable grid and have two columns which called type and value and they are edited by combo box. Now I want when the type combo box is set, the value combo box will be trigger as click on drop down arrow. How can I do this action?

Answer (score 0):

Per the ExtJS 2.3 docs, the ComboBox element's .expand() method can be called to pop it open. I suspect that will get you want you need. If you actually need to simulate the click event, things will be messy.